# Use template variable as part of script src

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, paypal

I am trying to create a model payments popup where the user can upgrade their plan in a google apps script. In my `.gs` file I have:

```
function manageSubscription() {
  var title = 'subscribe';
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('subscribe');
  html.email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var htmlOutput = html.evaluate();
  htmlOutput.setTitle(title).setWidth(200).setHeight(200)
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, title);
}
```

In my `.html` file, I am trying to use that email address to pass it to paypal when they signup:

```
  <script id="paypal_js"></script> // how do I set the src???
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var src = 'https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=my-client-id&email=';
    document.getElementById('paypal_js').src = src+<?= email ?>;

    paypal.Buttons({
      createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.subscription.create({'plan_id': 'P-my-plan'});
      },
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        google.script.host.close();
      }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  });
  </script>
```

However, I get `ReferenceError: paypal is not defined` in the browser console. Oddly, I can do a simple 'alert();' and see that I am getting the email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with your code where use are using `paypal`,
You are dynamically adding `script` and I assume, you will be getting `paypal` as global object from this script.

**What you forgot is, at the time of your code execution of `paypal.Buttons`, `paypal` is not available in browser. Since, it's still probably fetching and evaluating code from script, you just included. You have to listen to script onload event and call your required functions after that.**

```
<script id="paypal_js"></script> // how do I set the src???
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var src = 'https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=my-client-id&email=';
    var scriptTag = document.getElementById('paypal_js')
    scriptTag.src = src+<?= email ?>;

    scriptTag.onload = function() {
      paypal.Buttons({
        createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.subscription.create({'plan_id': 'P-my-plan'});
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          google.script.host.close();
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    }
  });
  </script>
```